Enforce Xcode to update String Catalog on command line?
Xcode's String Catalog seems to be a nice solution compared to the old approach. However, in larger projects it can happen that the Localizable.xcstrings file is updated too late, making developers checking in all the changes into Git except the changes from the Localizable.xcstrings.
I hoped setting LOCALIZATION_PREFERS_STRING_CATALOGS and SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS to YES could possibly solve the issue, but it didn't.
Locally on your machine it can often feel like the String Catalog is updated directly after compilation. But this is not consistent. Even it would be consistent, a developer could still forget to check them into Git or even decide to not do it for some reason. That's why I'm looking for a way to enforce the String Catalog update, so that on CI a simple git status check detects uncommitted changes of the String Catalog. Maybe I'm overlooking something but at the moment I have the feeling xcodebuild does not play well with String Catalogs.
